# bach echo variable substitution

Tags: bash, unix, echo

I want make a query wiht this bash code.

```
##fist I will extrac the table name from table.txt file
table=$(head -n 1 tables.txt)

#In this code is where I will make the substitution on the query
result=`echo "select 'result '||segment_name||':'||MB||':'||TOTAL_MB from (
   select TSEG.segment_name,round(TSEG.bytes/1024/1024) MB,l.segment_name as     LSEGMENT_NAME,nvl(l.MB,0) as LOB_MB,nvl(l.MB,0)+round(TSEG.bytes/1024/1024) as TOTAL_MB
  from dba_segments tseg,    (select LOBS.table_name,round(bseg.bytes/1024/1024)     MB,lobs.SEGMENT_NAME
       from dba_lobs lobs,dba_segments bseg
       where LOBS.SEGMENT_NAME=bseg.segment_name
       order by bseg.bytes asc
    ) l
   where TSEG.segment_type='TABLE'
   and TSEG.segment_name='$table'
   and TSEG.SEGMENT_NAME=l.table_name(+)
     order by TOTAL_MB
   )where rownum=1;`
```

my problem is on line TSEG.segment_name='$table', I need the table name on format 'TABLE_NAME'.

this is my actual ouput with table named "AABLG":

```
select 'result '||segment_name||':'||MB||':'||TOTAL_MB from (
   select TSEG.segment_name,round(TSEG.bytes/1024/1024) MB,l.segment_name as     LSEGMENT_NAME,nvl(l.MB,0) as LOB_MB,nvl(l.MB,0)+round(TSEG.bytes/1024/1024) as TOTAL_MB
  from dba_segments tseg,    (select LOBS.table_name,round(bseg.bytes/1024/1024)     MB,lobs.SEGMENT_NAME
       from dba_lobs lobs,dba_segments bseg
       where LOBS.SEGMENT_NAME=bseg.segment_name
       order by bseg.bytes asc
     ) l
   where TSEG.segment_type='TABLE'
'  and TSEG.segment_name='AABLG
   and TSEG.SEGMENT_NAME=l.table_name(+)
     order by TOTAL_MB
   )where rownum=1;
```

you can see that the " ' " is on the first position, and I don't know why.

regards.
Marco.

Comment: One point of clarification: `echo` doesn't do substitution at all -- echo just combines its arguments with whitespace, prints them to stdout, and adds a newline at the end. The substitution all happens *before* `echo` is called, and in the exact same way it would with any non-`echo` command.

Comment: Anyhow, the newline is probably caused by your `tables.txt` being a DOS-formatted text file, and thus having a stray `\r` at the end of each line. Use a tool such as `dos2unix` to convert it, or do as my code sample does and set `IFS' to a value that will trim it implicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be much better done without `echo` at all. Consider, for instance:

```
IFS=$'\r\n ' read -r table <tables.txt
IFS= read -r -d '' result <<EOF
select 'result '||segment_name||':'||MB||':'||TOTAL_MB from (
   select TSEG.segment_name,round(TSEG.bytes/1024/1024) MB,l.segment_name as     LSEGMENT_NAME,nvl(l.MB,0) as LOB_MB,nvl(l.MB,0)+round(TSEG.bytes/1024/1024) as TOTAL_MB
  from dba_segments tseg,    (select LOBS.table_name,round(bseg.bytes/1024/1024)     MB,lobs.SEGMENT_NAME
       from dba_lobs lobs,dba_segments bseg
       where LOBS.SEGMENT_NAME=bseg.segment_name
       order by bseg.bytes asc
    ) l
   where TSEG.segment_type='TABLE'
   and TSEG.segment_name='$table'
   and TSEG.SEGMENT_NAME=l.table_name(+)
     order by TOTAL_MB
   ) where rownum=1;
EOF
```

This also fixes the bug observed in your question by setting `IFS` to a value that includes `$'\r'`, the carriage-return character found in DOS-formatted newlines, and thus stripping such characters when they exist at the end of the first line of `tables.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for reply Charles. You answered my problem was the carriage-return character, the tables.txt file was edited on windows.